# Can we use backward elmination or forward selection for feature selection involving mixed data types?

Tags: r, feature-selection, mixed-type-data

I have a loan data where I need to predict the ratings whose class is factor. I have both numeric and factor variables influencing the ratings. I want to know if I can use backward elimination process to select the important variables.

Comment: Is there any reason you think that may cause it not to work? As long as the model you're using can handle both data types, I wouldn't see any problem in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the stepwise algorithm is taking the number of parameters into account, and the algorithm can recognize the different types, forward or backwards are just as valid as with only one type. E.g., if using AIC or F-Tests.

However, keep in mind that stepwise regression of any kind does not necessarily identify whether variables are "important". If by "importance" you mean good predictors, then perhaps this stepwise selection is OK (although I can't say I would ever use it myself - do a google and you will find no shortage of people explaining why stepwise procedures are not appropriate). However, if by "important" you mean relevant to your understanding of the subject area, stepwise procedures are dubious.